# Why are my if statements in java always returning false?

Tags: java, if-statement

I want to find out why the second if statement in this code always returns false, so every time I click the 'go' button in my program it shows incorrect password. Anyone have any ideas?

```
package Main;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;

public class CodexConsoleEngine extends CodexConsoleWindow implements ActionListener {  

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        boolean isPasswordEntered = false;
        JButton clickedButton = (JButton) e.getSource();
        String commandSent;
        String passwordSet = "password";
        char[] charPasswordEntered = password.getPassword();
        String passwordEntered = charPasswordEntered.toString();

        if(!isPasswordEntered){
            if(passwordEntered.equals(passwordSet)){
                consoleOutput.append("Correct password\n");
            }else{
                consoleOutput.append("Incorrect password\n");
            }
    }else{
        consoleOutput.append("You have already entered your password");
    }
}

}
```

Sorry for any obvious mistakes, I've only started java recently. REALLY recently.

EDIT: I've edited the code to use the .equals() method, but it still doesn't work. Could it have anything to do with the toString() method or the fact that I'm using JPasswordField?

Comment: Compare `String` contents with the `equals` method, not with the `==` operator.

Comment: For that updated code, are you sure you want `charPasswordEntered.toString()` and not `new String(charPasswordEntered)`?

Comment: I figured it out. I changed the passwordEntered variable to equal `String.valueOf(charPasswordEntered)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
if(!isPasswordEntered){
        if(passwordEntered.equals(passwordSet)) {
```

Comment: Hmm, doesn't seem to work. I added in a little extra thing to tell me what the password I entered was read as, and now it's the right password, but it used to be gibberish. However, it still says incorrect password in the consoleOutput field...

Answer (score 0):

To compare Strings use `String.equals()` method
for example in your code it should be `if(passwordEntered.equals(passwordSet))`
or you can use `String.equalsIgnoreCase()` to ignore capitalization

Answer (score 0):

You are incorrectly testing for equality with the Strings `passwordEntered` and `passwordSet`.

To correctly testing for equality in Strings use [String.equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) or [String.equalsIgnoreCase](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29) for a case insensitive equality test.